# OpenVPN route ip range includes server ip

Tags: networking, openvpn

my client route config is something like this

...
route 34.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
route 43.239.0.0 255.255.0.0
route 52.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
route 54.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
...

my openvpn server is on Amazon AWS EC2 instance(54.249.xx.xxx), so I have to exclude the server itself from routing table.
is there a good way to exclude specific ip address(54.249.xx.xxx) from ip range(54.0.0.0)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **more specific** route that overrides it. Routes are ordered by prefix length – i.e. number of bits in the netmask, so `255.255.255.255` will always win over any other route.

In route configuration, use the special `net_gateway` as the gateway address. It will automatically refer to the client's "old" gateway, and as a result will "exclude" the host:

```
route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

(Yes, literally like that. OpenVPN will *automatically* substitute both `remote_host` and `net_gateway` at the time of connection.)

Comment: You know you can Upvote/accept as answer..